# Find variables in a formula python

Tags: python

when I write a code like this,

`print(A3*2)`

python gives me this error:

`NameError: name 'A3' is not defined`

I'm trying to understand how python finds variables that are not defined and gives me errors like this.

I want to find variables from given formula and make a list from them. Like this:

```
>>>formula = (a = b3*2*C2)
variables = [a, b3, C2]
```

Comment: The error ' name 'A3' is not defined' means that the variable A3 is not defined. This means that the variable A3 is not initialised in your code. You first need to give the variable A3 a value (we say 'assign' A3 a value). So you can assign A3 with the value 1 for example ```A3=1``` and the code will work. If you have allready assigned A3 a value, please post your full code.

Comment: I know how to solve this error code but that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: _"I'm trying to understand how python finds variables that are not defined and gives me errors "_ - well, you asked for help regarding the error code. If you meant something else, please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not rely on error processing here. It should be better to get the formula as a string and parse it with the `ast` module.

Example:

```
import ast
formula = 'a = b3*2*C2'           # get the formula as a string
parsed = ast.parse(formula)       # parse it
for elt in ast.walk(parsed):      # walk down the parsed tree
    if isinstance(elt, ast.Name): # only process variable names
       print(elt.id)                # print that name
```

It would give:

```
a
C2
b3
```

To produce a list of the variable names, you could use a comprehension:

```
names = [i.id for i in ast.walk(ast.parse(formula)) if isinstance(i, ast.Name)]
print(names)
```

would give:

```
['a', 'C2', 'b3']
```